# What other heroes are from the Hylian race?

Tags: legend-of-zelda-series

Just having a look at the [Zeldapedia on Hylians](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Hylian), the opening paragraph suggests that aside from Link, there have been many Hylian heroes:

> The Hylians, also known as the Hylia people, are a recurring race of humans in the Legend of Zelda series. Creatures that worship the goddess Hylia, from which their name derives, the Hylians are the original race of Hyrule. It is said that they were created by the Goddesses Or Oocca race. Physically, Hylians resemble other humans, and the only difference appearance-wise between them is the Hylians' long, elf-like ears that supposedly enable them to hear special messages from the goddessess. It is shown that Hylians have an extended life-span, to the point of living for centuries. Their heritage also gives them unique psychic and magical abilities. **The Hylians have therefore given birth to many heroes through the ages, most notably Link.**

So aside from Link, which other heroes were there, or are they merely suggesting the multiple incarnations of Link *are* the "other [Hylian] heroes"?

Comment: there's a list on that link though?

Comment: @Aequitas there is only one that I can determine - "Princess Hilda", the rest seem to be just a list of all characters in each game. For example the Maku Tree from oracles of ages/seasons is also listed.

Comment: @Aequitas A list of what? I checked the link and the only list was a list of games that can be expanded to list all the enemies, characters, items, and map locations of each game. I don't think that's a list of Hylian heroes.

Comment: @nukeforum notable members, I thought they may have had what op wanted

Comment: Notable Hylian heroes. That's what I am looking for. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: What is meant by 'Notable' though? Notable as in, had their own game? Mentioned in game as being a hero?

Comment: @Robotnik Qualifies as "Hero"..?

Comment: @Ben - exactly! What is a 'hero'? Some random warrior that won a battle in the past? Do they need to be central to a plot point? Does the story revolve around them in some way, do they have some ancient statue of them or does the player character meet them for advice or something?, Or do you mean just a passing reference mentioned in cutscenes or in the game manual etc? What do you qualify as a 'hero'?

Comment: @Robotnik It's not what *I* qualify as a hero, it's what the series qualifies as a hero. I'm not certain of the criteria

Comment: Given that this is from an unofficial fan-maintained wiki, I'd be more inclined to believe it's a slip-up by the writer than a reference. I can't really recall any Hylian "hero" being mentioned in the game other than the various incarnations of Link. (Admittedly maybe the developers have mentioned something I'm not aware of.)

Comment: Since this has been bumped anyway, you guys are aware than other than Ocarina of Time / Majora's Mask; Oracle of Ages / Oracle of Seasons; and Wind Waker / Phantom Hourglass, all the Links are different people?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what this text is referring to is the **many incarnations of Link**.  In each Legend of Zelda game, you play as a [similar but distinct hero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_%28The_Legend_of_Zelda%29).  This is why you are able to name your character, and none of the Green-clad heroes are ever officially referred to as "Link" in-game.  There don't appear to be many if any other references to great heroes of Hylian descent, or at least I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

The only example that comes to mind is The King of Hyrule. Since he assists Link very noticeably in Wind Waker, it seems like a given that he is recognized as a hero of some kind.